# How to copy data of one excel sheet in another using batch file

Tags: php, batch-file, phpexcel

I have bunch of excel files with **same name** in two different folders, lets say folder A & B.

Now i need to copy data of files in folder A to respective same name files in folder B but in different sheet and then rename the new sheet with current month and year.

I need to achieve this in batch file or php script. Please can any one help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its very unlikely you will be able to do this easily with a batch script or in php because .xls files are compressed.

A much easier way to achieve what you need would be to use a VBA macro in one of your excel files as VBA supports all the operations you would need to achieve such a process.

Comment: I have not used VBA ever. No way to do by batch processing or in php?

Comment: @Penny I highly highly doubt it being possible in Batch. It seems there are some PHP libraries that deal with excel that you could use like this one https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/. I have no experience using this library though so im not sure how easy it would be to use.

Comment: Yes I came across phpexcel and trying to understand how to use them.

Comment: Using PHPExcel, iterate over all files in folder A, load each file in turn, rename the worksheet you want to change, save the file to folder B, flush the workbook from memory, repeat

Comment: Thanks Mark. I used PHPExcel but copying data from one excel file to another I am still not  getting that part, facing errors like `Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Reader_TOP_QUERIES-abc.com.au.csv' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHPExcel-develop\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php on line 170`